# React Native using CameraRoll

Tags: android, react-native, android-camera, camera-roll

In React-native I am trying to access videos and images saved on `CameraRoll` but when I fetch records I only retrieve images stored by whatsapp. I tried to use `groupTypes` param for fetching everything, but it seems like this param is not supported by `Android` as it gives the following error: `cameraRoll groupTypes is not supported on android`.

Does anyone know how to retrieve all the images and videos using CameraRoll in android too? Here is the code I am using:

```
let fetchParams = {assetType: 'All', first: 10}; //assetType: All, Videos, Photos
CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams).then(this.storeMedia.bind(this)).catch(this.logMediaError.bind(this));
```

Comment: Seems like react-native `cameraRoll` only checks images table. I extended it by checking Files table and started using the extended version as a native module. Here is the gist for that: https://gist.github.com/cubbuk/70e0841ec5e0ebfe80c6f747eb973216

Comment: Did you ever figure out a cleaner way of doing this? I just ran into this problem. Only images are showing on Android.

Comment: sorry @Keng I didn't work on that part after this or heard any news about it.